# Where have my addons gone

Tags: add-on

I launch Blender today and hit the N key to bring up my addons and they have gone.
Makehuman, Construction lines etc.
I go to preference and check, but all addons gone except the standard install ones.
Update Blender to latest version.
I cannot install any addons even the zipped ones I have.
It seems something has broken.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Did you download it from the Microsoft store? If you did that, try downloading from blender's own website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just updated your Blender version you need to look in the same directory as your installation. Under Windows it should be somewhere like `C:\Users\[user profile]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation`

Make sure you turn on "View Hidden Files" to see the Appdata folder.

Then once you go into Blender Foundation folder you should see several versions of blender like, 2.93, 3.0, 3.2 etc. Click into the most recent one before your update,  follow the path  into `3.x/scripts/` and copy the `addons` folder. Then navigate to the same place in the newer version of Blender that you just updated to and paste it the addons folder there.

I'm on Linux so I can't give an exact step by step but the process is essentially the same for both systems.

I would also recommend enabling the [Blender Cloud addon](https://studio.blender.org/blog/introducing-blender-sync/) that comes with Blender. Really takes the headache out of stuff like this.